# Python frames auto resizing

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have created 4 frames, but when try to pack a label in my 4th frame, all frames get auto-resized, can anyone please have a look and advise what wrong thing I am doing. I am new to python and using python 3.6.

```
from tkinter import *
import time

localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))

root = Tk()
x = root.winfo_screenwidth()
y = root.winfo_screenheight()

root.geometry("%dx%d+0+0" %(x,y))
root.resizable(0,0)

frameinfo = Frame(root, width=x, height=100 , bg='powder blue', relief=SUNKEN)
frameinfo.pack(side=TOP,fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

framebutton = Frame(root, width=300, height=y-100, bg='dark grey', relief=SUNKEN)
framebutton.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

frameradio = Frame(root, width=x-300, height=50, bg='light yellow', relief=SUNKEN)
frameradio.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

frameinput = Frame(root, width=x-300, height=y-150,  bg='light green')
frameinput.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

clock = Label(frameinfo, font =('aerial', 30, 'bold'), fg='blue', bg='powder blue')
clock.pack(side=RIGHT)
lblinfo = Label(frameinfo, text = "Cloning Tool", font =('aerial', 40, 'bold'), fg='black', bg='powder blue').pack()

def tick():
    s =time.strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S')
    clock.config(text=s)
    clock.after(200,tick)
tick()

butCapClone = Button(framebutton, text='Clone', borderwidth=5,width=20,height=2, font=9, command=showcapwindow).grid(row=0, padx=10, pady=20)
butexitClone = Button(framebutton, text='Exit', borderwidth=5,width=20,height=2, font=9, command=root.quit).grid(row=1, padx=10, pady=4)

modes = [('None','0'),('CAP','1'),('CAPTWO v1','2'),('CAPTWO v2','3'),]
radioclonetype = IntVar()
radioclonetype.set('0')

for text,mode in modes:
    Radiobutton(frameradio, text=text, variable=radioclonetype, value=mode, font=('aerial',15), bg='light yellow', fg='purple').pack(side=LEFT)

labelprojectcode = Label(frameinput, text = "Project code(3 Characters")
labelprojectcode.pack(side=TOP)
# inputprojectcode = Entry(frameinput, fg='black', font=('aerial',15,'bold')).grid(row=0,column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't see the frames shrinking when I run your code.

Comment: Hi Bryan, Thank for looking into the code.

Comment: can you comment below code and see the difference in frames                      # labelprojectcode = Label(frameinput, text = "Project code(3 Characters").grid(row=0)
# inputprojectcode = Entry(frameinput, fg='black', font=('aerial',15,'bold')).grid(row=0,column=1)

Comment: No. Please put any code updates in the question by clicking the [edit] link. Code in the comment section is impossible to read.

Answer (score 0):

Frames expand or shrink based on the children widget size demand, given that there is extra space.Your label overfits my 1980x1080 resolution and that last frame's content becomes no longer visible. Comment out `root.resizable(0,0)` to see what happens:

```
#root.resizable(0,0)
```

This seems to be because `pack` works relative to sibling `pack`s and the last called `pack` is given the minimum amount of space it requires while still fitting the options given to all `pack`s. For example swap the position of:

```
frameradio.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
```

with:

```
frameinput.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
```

You will get almost a completely new layout.